# Why are << and += building a different string?

Tags: ruby, string

I wrote a function that iterates over a string character by character, pulling values from a hash using each character as a key. The values in the hash were used to build a new string:

```
acc = ''
str.each_char do |c|
  acc << somehash[c]
end
```

If the string was longer than one, the first character would be looked up and its hash value be interpolated several times in the built string, which was not what I wanted. I rewrote the line with `<<` as

```
acc += somehash[c]
```

and it behaved correctly.
Why am I getting different behavior from `<<` and `+=`?

NOTE: I'm no longer getting this behavior, and my unit tests are passing. I'm not sure why since I didn't touch the logic in the loop.

Comment: [`String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) uses the same string, `str = str + 'a'` reassigns the result to the newly created string object. I can’t realize, how your code could produce the behaviour you’ve described.

Comment: Honestly i would go with `acc = str.chars.map{|c| somehash[c]}.join` it's cleaner and will produce the same result. Or better yet `acc = somehash.values_at(*str.split(//)).join`

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah, that's what I thought. I had always used '<<' happily until today when my unit tests uncovered the strange interpolation.

Comment: I'm confused because after continuing coding for several hours, I switched back the the shovel and now my unit tests are fine with it. I wish I knew the cause since I didn't change the logic of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s1 << s2` appends the string `s2` to `s1`, whereas `s1 += s2`, which expands to `s1 = s1 + s2`, creates a new object which becomes the new value of the variable `s1`.

Consider the following.

```
s1 = "ab"
s1.object_id #=> 70117580969460 
s2 = "cd"

s1 << s2     #=> "abcd" 
s1           #=> "abcd" 
s1.object_id #=> 70117580969460
```

Compare that with:

```
s1 = "ab"
s1.object_id #=> 70117576935280 
s2 = "cd"

s1 += s2     #=> s1 = s1 + s2 => "abcd" 
s1           #=> "abcd" 
s1.object_id #=> 70117576870900
```